# Is there a way to normalize json data from NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

It seems that since XCode 6.1, the iPhone 5S, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ simulators (all 64-bit) all return data from the following system method differently (keys are ordered differently) than their 32-bit simulator counterparts (e.g. iPhone 5 simulator)

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithJSONObject:(id)obj options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error;
```

This difference of key ordering caused a problem for me since we calculate the SHA1 of that JSON data (converted to NSString*) and use it for a validation test. Since the ordering changed, the SHA1 changed and the validation fails.

Simplified sample code (non-ARC) to get the SHA1 is below:

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
NSString * json = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

NSString * sha1 = [MyUtils computeSHA1:json];

+(NSString*) computeSHA1:(NSString*)input
{
    const char *cstr = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData     *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];
    NSNumber* dataLen = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:data.length];

    uint8_t    digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, dataLen.unsignedIntValue, digest);

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return output;
}
```

Apparently, this key ordering difference doesn't happen on the actual devices (previous behavior was preserved).

I also tried with the `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` option but the JSON ordering is still inconsistent between simulators.

So, the question is: Does anyone have a recommendation on how to normalize such JSON data so as to not be susceptible to key ordering changes? Alternately, is there any way to get the previous (32-bit simulator) behavior?

Comment: Elements in a JSON "object" are not in a defined order, nor are keys in an NSDictionary in a defined order.  Any code that depends on the order of JSON object entries or NSDictionary entries is defective.

Comment: In retrospect, I agree that it is unwise to checksum a JSON string that's derived from an (NS)Dictionary and use it for validation, but this is after deployment and the potential problem that the key order could change in future releases never came up by anyone in an entire team (of n people). Prior to this week, it also never manifested as a real problem. Although there is value in illustrating how this is a poor idea, the question here is how to make it work or how it could have been made to work.

Comment: What can I say -- it sounds like the folks in your team kinda missed a biggie.  If you need the JSON ordered somehow someone on your team is going to have to write some ugly code to do it.  There are some open source JSON serializers floating around that one could cannibalize.

Comment: Not sure why this question is getting downvoted as there's probably still some value in learning why it isn't a good idea to checksum your JSON and use that checksum for validation.

Comment: If you need compatibility with existing data out there, I'd recommend using two checksum algorithms, the original one and one that sorts the keys.  Generate new checksums with sorted keys, and try both algorithms on existing data before deciding you have a checksum mismatch.

Comment: Well, maybe it's because there's still some value in reading the documentation.

Comment: Of course, another option is to simply not expect the checksum to be the same after deserialization/serialization, but to check it before deserializing and create a new one when serializing.  Or never re-serialize, but simply save the original and pass it on if unchanged.

Comment: I didn't add this to the question originally, but I'll add it to direct the answers: The serialized JSON string on the client side is an "application definition", the checksum of which is sent to a server. The server then checks to see if it has that "application definition checksum" in its store. If it doesn't then a connection is refused ("I don't have that application"). If it does, then the connection is allowed ("I have that application"). Since the checksum is changing on the client, the server refuses connection. The workaround is to add more application definitions on the server.

Comment: If given the same JSON structure loaded into dict1 and dict2, if `[[dict1 mySHA1] isEqual:[dict2 mySHA1]] == false` sometimes, while `[dict1 isEqualToDictionary:dict2]` is always true, then something is very wrong with your base assumptions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The code below (non-ARC) worked for me to better canonicalize JSON output. The code assumes the class methods below are all in a class called MyUtils.

Simply pass the the NSDictionary to serialize into "canonicalized JSON" to `canonicalJSONRepresentationWithDictionary:`

The returned NSString* then contains serialized JSON that has the keys ordered lexicographically/alphabetically in a non-human readable format.

```
+(NSString *) canonicalJSONRepresentationWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSMutableString* json = [NSMutableString string];
    [json appendString:@"{"];

    NSArray* keys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* a, NSString* b) {
        return [a compare:b];
    }];

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.count; i++) {
        NSString* key = keys[i];
        [json appendFormat:@"\"%@\":", key];

        if ([dict[key] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            [json appendFormat:@"\"%@\"", [MyUtils canonicalJSONRepresentationWithString:dict[key]]];
        } else if ([dict[key] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [json appendString:[MyUtils canonicalJSONRepresentationWithDictionary:dict[key]]];
        } else if ([dict[key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [json appendString:[MyUtils canonicalJSONRepresentationWithArray:dict[key]]];
        } else {
            return nil;
        }

        if (i < keys.count - 1) {
            [json appendString:@","];
        }
    }

    [json appendString:@"}"];
    return json;
}

+(NSString *) canonicalJSONRepresentationWithArray:(NSArray *) array
{
    NSMutableString* json = [NSMutableString string];
    [json appendString:@"["];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        if ([array[i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            [json appendFormat:@"\"%@\"", [MyUtils canonicalJSONRepresentationWithString:array[i]]];
        } else if ([array[i] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [json appendString:[MyUtils canonicalJSONRepresentationWithDictionary:array[i]]];
        } else if ([array[i] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [json appendString:[MyUtils canonicalJSONRepresentationWithArray:array[i]]];
        } else {
            return nil;
        }

        if (i < array.count - 1) {
            [json appendString:@","];
        }
    }

    [json appendString:@"]"];
    return json;
}

+(NSString *) canonicalJSONRepresentationWithString:(NSString *) string;
{
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:string, @"a", nil];

    NSError  * error;
    NSData   * jsonData = nil;
    NSString * json     = nil;

    jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                               options:0
                                                 error:&error];

    if (!jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error serializing json: %@", error);
        return nil;
    } else {
        json = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    }

    NSRange colonQuote = [json rangeOfString:@":\""];
    NSRange lastQuote = [json rangeOfString:@"\"" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(colonQuote.location + 2, lastQuote.location - colonQuote.location - 2);

    NSString* rc = [json substringWithRange:range];

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: The above code does not handle NSNumber or NSNull, nor does it escape "special" characters in strings, and hence it is not complete/correct.  One would be more advised to take an existing open source JSON serializer and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Key ordering in dictionaries is not guaranteed. If you need them sorted, put them into an array and sort them.

Comment: Also, Apple does not provide any kind of ordered dictionary class and creating your own by subclassing `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` should be done with great caution since they are both part of a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).

Comment: Instead of "not guaranteed" perhaps better would be "does not exist".

Comment: Yes, but sorting the keys in an array would need to be done not just for top-level keys but all keys within other objects.